# Confused As To Why This Function Does Not Call?

Tags: vb.net, function

I'm trying to call this function into a procedure and am confused on why this is not working, I've looked up how to format a function call and don't understand my mistakes.

```
Structure Stock
    Dim category As String
    Dim price As Integer
    Dim size As String
    Dim sku As String
    Dim color As String
End Structure

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim stockArray() As String =
        IO.File.ReadAllLines("stockInventory.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub btnNewSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewSave.Click
    Dim answer
    answer = check(sku, stockArray)

End Sub

Function check(sku, stockArray) As Boolean
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim numVar = -1

    numVar = Array.IndexOf(stockArray, txtSKU.Text)

    If numVar = -1 Then
        flag = False
    End If

    If numVar <> -1 Then
        flag = True
    End If

    Return flag
End Function
```

It gives me an error saying,

> sku is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection
>   level

I have a structure where sku is defined as being a string. Do I have to declare it again in this sub for it to work?

Comment: what do you mean "does not call"? Have you stepped through with the Visual Studio debugger to run each line and see if the function is called or not? If not, then what happens instead? An exception, maybe? Please be clear about what is actually happening when you run the code, and any errors you get. If you haven't used the debugger on it, then please do so now before replying. Apart from the fact I can't see where `sku` and `stockArray` were defined before you ran `answer = check(sku, stockArray)` (did you leave some relevant code out of the question??), I can't see much wrong with this.

Comment: @ADyson It gives me an error saying, "sku is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" I have a structure where sku is defined as being a string. Do I have to declare it again in this sub for it to work?

Comment: Maybe. It depends where you declared it. Or perhaps you just need to change its access modifier. P.S. in future if you get an error (this is a compiler error, so you should have seen it immediately), then add it to the question from the beginning. Errors are vital clues, not secondary details.

Comment: @ADyson It is declared in the form, I would think this would globalize its availability

Comment: You mean the same form as the code above? Perhaps you just need to change its access modifier or something. I don't know...show me the code in context and it's much easier to say. Descriptions of code are very hard to fix :-)

Comment: yes, same form as above. I'm not sure how to format code in comments. I'll figure it out, thank you though. @ADyson

Comment: P.S. you realise that in the function `check()` the input parameter you named `sku`  is never actually used within the function? Do you even need it?

Comment: Don't add the code in the comments, edit your question instead. (The "edit" button is at the bottom left of the question under the blue tags)

Comment: @ADyson Fixed so that you can see the structure, thank you. It gives me the same error message for **stockArray** too. Noticed your comment about sku not being used, I'm not sure why it's there to be honest. I'm rushing and not checking.

Comment: Ok well if you don't need it then... `Function check(stockArray) As Boolean` and `answer = check(stockArray)` ...problem solved

Comment: But regarding the original error, you should probably read about how to actually use a Structure, and a value within it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/structure-variables . Here's a basic example of how to use a Structure such as the one you created: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ltlWDf . You can't a) use a Structure without assigning an instance of it to a variable first, or b) randomly refer to properties within the structure out of context. You just used "sku" as if it was a variable in its own right, but it's not.

Comment: As for `stockArray`, it is only declared within the "Form1_Load" function, so it simply doesn't exist outside that scope. For it to be accessible outside the Form1_Load function you'd have to declare it at class level (and then of course you can still assign a value to it during Form1_Load). Perhaps you should read some conceptual stuff about the scope of variables, too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/how-to-control-the-scope-of-a-variable

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your help and not getting frustrated with my intellectual ignorance and beginner's mistakes. I'm pretty much teaching myself vb.net because I was assigned a semester long project and lots of the material I have yet to learn is not covered.

Comment: No problem, hope it helped. Good luck with your project. I would maybe buy yourself a decent book on VB.NET so you have a solid coherent reference to refer to when you need to understand key concepts.

Comment: Variable sku is not found because you haven't declared it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fine-tune this code a bit:

```
Function check(ByVal stockArray as String()) As Boolean
    Return Array.IndexOf(stockArray, txtSKU.Text) >= 0
End Function
```

It'll return if the element is in the Array.

If your file is very very large and you are doing many searches, I recommend storing in a HashSet instead of an array to get O(1) searching, instead of the O(n) you are getting.

I notice your stock array, has to be declared at the class level, not the method level, to be accessible by other methods.